# Server Side Google Markers Clustering - Python/Django

Tags: python, django, json, google-maps, markerclusterer

After experimenting with client side approach to clustering large numbers of Google markers I decided that it won't be possible for my project (social network with 28,000+ users).

Are there any examples of clustering the coordinates on the server side - preferably in Python/Django?

The way I would like this to work is to gradually index the markers based on their proximity (radius) and zoom level.

In another words when a new user registers he/she is automatically assigned to a certain 'group' of markers that are close to each other thus increasing the 'group's' counter. What's being send to the server is just a small number of 'groups'. Only when the zoom level/scale of map is 1:1 - actual users are shown on the map.

That way the client side will have to deal only with 10-50 markers per request/zoom level.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.maptimize.com/) is a paid service that uses server-side clustering, but I'm not sure how it works.  I'm guessing that they just use your data to generate the markers to be shown at each zoom level.

**Update:** [This tutorial](http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/11/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps) demonstrates a basic server-side clustering function.  It's written in PHP for the Static Maps API, but you could use it as a starting point.

Comment: I know about their service but I want to have full control of the code.

Comment: the tutorial is useful but the algorithm might be too slow for 28,000 points.  clustering based on a grid is clumsy but a lot faster obviously.

Comment: @Tom - an algorithm like this would definitely be too slow on the client-side, but I think it might be possible server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) and [OPTICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm) pages on wikipedia, these looks very suitable for clustering places on a map. There is also a page about [Cluster Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) that shows all the possible algorithms you can use, most would be trivial to implement using the language of your choice.

With 28k+ points, you might want to skip django and just jump into C/C++ directly, and surely not expect this to get calculated in real-time in response to web requests.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to define a grid with a unit size based on the zoom level.  So you collect up all the items within a grid by lat,lon to one decimal place.  An example is 42.2x73.4.  So a point at 42.2003x73.4021 falls in that grid cell.  That cell is bounded by 42.2x73.3 and 42.2x73.5.

If there are one or more points in a grid cell, you place a marker in the center of that grid.

You then hook up the zoomend event and change your grid size accordingly, and redraw the markers.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.zoomend

Comment: Wouldn't this be slow when the entire map needs to be visible and you have 30k markers to load?

Answer (score -1):

You can try my server-side clustering django app:

https://github.com/biodiv/anycluster

It prvides a kmeans and a grid cluster.